# LCD Monitor screen keeps going blank

Tags: display, hardware-failure, lcd

I have an LG LCD monitor (Flatron L192WS). I've been using it since 5 years, never had a problem but from yesterday onwards suddenly after 20-10 minutes of working, the LCD screen goes blank.
When the screen is blank, the power LED on the monitor is still ON and the power and HDD LEDs of the CPU are also on. When I turn the monitor's power off and turn it back on, the screen appears and it could be seen that all the processing of the system works fine then it once again works for 15-20 minutes, sometimes even longer and again the screen goes blank.

Can anyone help me understand what could be the problem?

Also, could it be some sort of virus/malware or is it purely a hardware fault?

Comment: Perfectly white? Whiter that usual? Would seem like a hardware fault. Maybe some piece of the electronics is overheating. Or you could have a faulty cable.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard not white actually, the screen is turning off completely, like no display...

Comment: This may sound strange... but there is a possibility your screen overheating and it shuts itself down to avoid damage. Is the monitor warm? (the grill on the backside maybe full of dust?)

Comment: @Darius Yes, the monitor does get very hot. could the dust be the reason for such a thing?

Comment: @RohanShah Very possible. I don't have an experience with just a monitor "going blank" like you, but iMac going blank (aka froze/bsod) due to heating up iMac.. we have a few of those in our workplace. Try cleaning up the dust stuck on the grill with can of air (when the monitor turned off of course), and wipe out with alcohol wipes the sticky dust. Or just use a strong vacuum (dyson comes into mind) to try sucking up all the dust and see if the monitor gets to a more stable temperature and not heating up too much, and hopefully not blanking out.

Comment: Could it be the problem of capacitors? Is my problem similar to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/287249/i-have-to-cycle-my-lcd-monitors-power-on-and-off-to-get-it-to-stay-on) ?

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue with your `Power Saving Settings.` If you open the `Control Panel` and go into the `Advanced Power Settings` via `Power Options` there will be an option called `PCI Express.` Expand that option and check the value of `Link State Power Management.` If that is set to anything other than Off, that could be causing the monitor screen to go blank.

I had a similar issue to yours a while back and this is how I managed to resolve mine. This may not work for you, but it's worth a try. If this is not the issue, it could be any number of other things.

I would first try and check if the problem persists with another cable. It may just be that the cable you're using is not making proper contact with the monitor/gpu and any slight movement is causing the screen to go blank.

If a new cable doesn't help you could try another connection on your GPU. The problem is most likely hardware related, but you could try a virus/malware scan to rule out that as a possible cause.

Comment: I checked it, the "link state power mgmt." is set to off... I will try changing the cable as well...

Comment: Cool :). Which graphics card are you using by the way? It could be a driver related issue.

Comment: I'm using GeForce 9500 GT. btw my graphics drivers are up to date.

Comment: Could it be the problem of capacitors? Is my problem similar to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/287249/i-have-to-cycle-my-lcd-monitors-power-on-and-off-to-get-it-to-stay-on) ?